# How to find general form of the inverse laplace transform?

Tags: laplace-transform, partial-fractions, inverse-laplace

I've been having trouble with understanding how to properly do partial-fraction decomposition on the inverse Laplace transform of
$$
F(s) = \frac{s+1}{(s^2+1)^2}
$$
I tried using the complex factors
$$
\frac{s+1}{(s^2+1)^2}=\frac{As+B}{(s-i)^2}+\frac{Cs+D}{(s+i)^2}
$$
Finding
$$
A = -\frac{i}{4} \\
B = -\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{4} \\
C = \frac{i}{4} \\
D = -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{4}
$$
But I have no clue how to proceed from here as I don't see a way to match this to any common laplace transforms.

I also tried this decomposition
$$
\frac{s+1}{(s^2+1)^2}=\frac{As+B}{s^2+1}+\frac{Cs+D}{(s^2+1)^2}
$$
Here I get
$$
A = 0 \\
B = 0 \\
C = 1 \\
D = 1
$$
Which simply brings me back to square 1.
If I look for what my course book gives as the general form I should arrive at for this problem, I find this:
$$
f(t) = ((At+B)sin(t)+(Ct+D)cos(t))\theta(t)
$$
where $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside step function.

How can I manipulate the original $F(s)$ to see this general form of $f(t)$?

Comment: There are common Laplace transforms for this, splitting the part with $s$ in the numerator to the part with $1$ in the numerator. https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/laplace_table.aspx . Lines 9 and 11

Answer (score 1):

I hope this gives you help otherwise, tell me to delete it. We know that:
$$
\mathcal{L}(t^nf(t))=(-1)^n\dfrac{d^nF}{ds^n}
$$
where $n$ is a positive integer. Use this fact and see that $\left(\dfrac{-0.5}{s^2+1}\right)'=\dfrac{s}{(1+s^2)^2}$. Moreover, apply the method pointed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2183179/8581) for the rest to find the inverse Laplace of $\dfrac{1}{(1+s^2)^2}$. I think you find the way!